# A question about an argument in Debarre's Higher dimensional algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space

I'm currently reading Debarre's book *Higher Dimensional Algebraic Geometry*. I'm having trouble understanding his argument on page 38 concerning the scheme $Mor_d(P^1_k,P^N_k)$ parametrizing morphisms of degree $d$ from the projective line over k to projective N-space. He begins by

> Let $k$ be a field. Any $k$-morphism $f$ from $P^1_k$ to $P^N_k$ can be written as ...

1. Isn't such a $k$-morphism merely a $k$-point in the scheme?
2. This argument (which is clear to me) leads to the following conclusion (with which I have no issue):

> Therefore, morphisms of degree $d$ from $P^1_k$ to $P^N_k$ are parametrized by a Zariski open set of the projective space $P((S^dk^2)^{N+1})$.

But then how does this statement on $k$-points of $Mor_d(P^1_k,P^N_k)$ lead to his following statement on the whole scheme $Mor_d(P^1_k,P^N_k)$?

> We denote this quasi-projective variety by $Mor_d(P^1_k,P^N_k)$.

In other words, what happens if we begin with any scheme over $k$ instead of the base field $k$ itself? Isn't that (i.e. describing all $S$-points for all schemes $S$ over $k$) what really characterizes the scheme $Mor_d(P^1_k,P^N_k)$? Or are $k$-points of $Mor_d(P^1_k,P^N_k)$ (which are the morphisms he begins with) enough in this case? (If yes, then why do they suffice?)

Am I missing any obvious steps?

Comment: Your question and phrasing is not clear at all.